# Filter rsyslog message by user

Tags: rsyslog

Is there any way to filter messages sent to rsyslog by user id? Let's say I want to ensure, that only messages sent by root should be logged to a separate file (based on rsyslog rules) and messages generated by non-privileged users (e.g. using logger utility) will be discarded.

Comment: AFAIK the UID is not even a standard, let alone a mandatory field in syslog messages so I am *fairly certain* you can't:  https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5424#page-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, at least for messages comming from SystemD's Journal.

Change the `load="imuxsock"` line in `/etc/rsyslog.conf` to:

```
module(load="imuxsock" SysSock.Annotate="on" SysSock.ParseTrusted="on")
```

Add to Syslog config:

```
if $!uid == '0'  then /var/log/root.log
if $!uid == '33' then /var/log/www-data.log
```

I have learnt this [here](http://rsyslog-users.1305293.n2.nabble.com/filter-by-UID-and-trusted-properties-not-working-td7588927.html).

**Optional**: if you want to add a 'classic' syslog Unix socket as input (not TCP) add this below the 'module' line:

```
input(type="imuxsock" Socket="/dev/rsyslog" Annotate="on" ParseTrusted="on")
```

The `$!uid` will also work for messages logged to this syslog socket.

Answer (score 0):

Can't test this right now, but shouldn't a line like this in the /etc/rsyslog.conf -file work?

```
root.*                        -/var/log/root_messages.log
```